# AMP: set setState to an inital value

Tags: amp-html

I have following code:

```
<p class="rechner">
<input type="number" name="Km" on="input-throttled:AMP.setState({a: event.valueAsNumber})" [value]="(b/1.61).toFixed(2)" value="1.00" size="6"> <label for="Km">Km</label> =
<input type="number" name="Mi" on="input-throttled:AMP.setState({b: event.valueAsNumber})" [value]="(a*1.61).toFixed(2)" value="1.61" size="6"> <label for="Mi">Meilen</label>
</p>
```

After change the first input value the var b takes the value 0 because b is not take the 2nd input.
How can I initalate both variable a and b for the first change?

Comment: Also would like to know how to do this. It's similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62003407/deep-merge-with-amp-setstate If @Sebastian-Benz comes online, he'll have a solution.

Comment: Hi @JayGray thanks for the releated topic. But this is a little bit over kill to use mustache and remote json for such a simple problem.

Comment: Hi i am not sure what's your question here, i just tested your line of code in amp playground and values do change. When i change value in KM it does change value of Meilen.

Comment: @RohitAmbre yes it changes, but it takes the value of 0 in the first request not the default value I set 1 or 1.61. The Value for a or b is NaN and not 1 or 1.6. So after the first change of the calc it shows the wrong calculation.